# recursive sub length - the longest series possible of ascending integers

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, substring

I'm trying to write a recursive function that receives an array and it's size and some other variables (of my choice). The function returns the length of the longest series possible of ascending integers in the array. The limitation is not using loops and not calling other functions or using pointers or other libraries.

This is the code I wrote, which unfortunately isn't working and I don't understand why!

```
length4 = max_set(arr4, size4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0);

int max_set(int arr[], int size, int max, int index1, int index2, int 
currentMax, int i) {
 int path1, path2;
 if (index1 == size)
     return currentMax;
 if (index2 == size){
     if (currentMax < max)
         currentMax = max;
     index1 = i + 1;
     index2 = index1 + 1;
     max = 1;
 }
 if (arr[index2]> arr[index1]){
     path1 = max_set(arr, size, max + 1, index1, index2 + 1, currentMax, i);
     path2 = max_set(arr, size, max + 1, index1 + 1, index2 + 1, currentMax, i);
 }
 path1 = max_set(arr, size, max, index1, index2 + 1, currentMax, i);
 path2 = max_set(arr, size, max, index1 + 1, index2 + 1, currentMax,i);
 if (path1 > path2)
    return path1;
 else
     return path2;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger! (Or failing that, to insert lots of printf statements throughout your code to see what's going on.)

Comment: You have an array of integers, what do you mean by largest sub string, largest sum?

Comment: oops sorry! i mean the longest series possible of ascending integers.

Comment: how about including a main() with a function call and expected output,

Comment: If that's what you mean, then edit the question and fix it.

Comment: i edited the question. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "longest series possible", do you mean longest series in the array or do you mean longest possible series by rearranging the numbers in the array in order (possibly removing duplicates)? i.e in `[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6]` would the answer be 4, 6 or 7?

Comment: I mean longest possible series without rearranging the order of the numbers in the array. For instance, for the array {3, 23, 2, 45, 0, 21, 80} it will return 4

Comment: OK, I'm now officially totally lost.

Comment: So from {**3**, **23**, 2, **45**, 0, 21, **80**}, the longest ascending sequence is the numbers in **bold** and has a length of 4?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

I found the original code more complicated than it needs to be for the task at hand, so rather than try and fix it, I just simplified it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * Determine maximum ascending sequence length using length so far.
 * @arr points to first element of array.
 * @size is length of array.
 * @pos is position of remaining entries in array.
 * @maxval is the maximum value included the sequence so far (if len > 0).
 * @len is sequence length so far.
 *
 * Returns maximum ascending sequence length.
 */
int max_set_recurse(int arr[], int size, int pos, int maxval, int len)
{
    int path1, path2, newlen;

    if (size <= pos) {
        /* Nothing left, so return sequence length so far. */
        return len;
    }
    /* Try skipping the first remaining entry. */
    path1 = max_set_recurse(arr, size, pos + 1, maxval, len);
    if (len && arr[pos] <= maxval) {
        /* First remaining entry is no larger than maximum value. */
        /* Try beginning sequence at first remaining entry. */
        newlen = 0;
    } else {
        /* Try extending the sequence with first remaining entry. */
        newlen = len + 1;
    }
    path2 = max_set_recurse(arr, size, pos + 1, arr[pos], newlen);
    /* Return the longest ascending sequence length of the two we tried. */
    return path2 > path1 ? path2 : path1;
}

/*
 * Determine maximum ascending sequence length
 * @arr points to entries.
 * @size is number of entries.
 *
 * Returns maximum ascending sequence length.
 */
int max_set(int arr[], int size)
{
    return max_set_recurse(arr, size, 0, 0, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[argc - 1];
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        arr[i - 1] = atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    printf("Longest ascending sequence length = %d\n", max_set(arr, argc - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

(**EDITED** to comply with "no pointers" rule as far as possible in C, i.e. no *overt* use of pointers, given that arrays are passed as pointers, and array indexing is actually pointer arithmetic and pointer dereferencing in disguise!)

The `max_set_recurse` function is called with the remaining portion of the array to be checked (from `pos` onwards), the maximum value in the partial maximum ascending sequence so far (if any), and the length of the partial maximum ascending sequence so far (possibly zero).

- If the remaining portion of the array is empty (`size <= pos`), just return the length of the sequence so far.
- Otherwise, we can determine two sequence lengths, one that excludes the first remaining entry in the array (`arr[pos]`), and one that includes it.  The function will return the maximum of these two sequence lengths.
- For the recursion path that excludes the first remaining entry in the array, the recursion call will skip the first remaining entry and pass through the previous maximum value and sequence length.
- For the recursion path that includes the first remaining entry in the array, the recursion call will skip the first remaining entry, use the value of the first remaining entry as the maximum value, and set the sequence length as follows:

  - if the previous length is zero, or the first remaining entry is greater than the previous maximum value, use the previous sequence length plus one;
  - otherwise, use a sequence length of zero.

The demo program is called with a sequence of numbers on the command line. It will print the length of the longest ascending sequence that can be found by skipping or including each element.

Here are some example command lines and outputs. I have marked the input numbers that form part of the longest sequence in **bold**, although the program does not report which numbers are part of the longest ascending sequence:

./ascend **3** **23** 2 **45** 0 21 **80**
`Longest ascending sequence length = 4`
./ascend 10 **3** **5** **23** 2 **45** 0 21 **80**
`Longest ascending sequence length = 5`
./ascend 10 **3** **5** 23 2 45 21 80 **20** **21** **22** **23**
`Longest ascending sequence length = 6`